# How to call JavaScript functions directly in Razor view between HTML tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor-pages, razorengine

I'm iterating a list in my Razor view and I have a date attribute to show in a specific format.

I have used `model.MyDatetimeAttr.toString("dd MMM yyy")` which is working fine. However it has considerable performance impact (taking too much time to load the page). That's why I want to use a JavaScript function to format my date attribute.

Something like this:

```
<div> FormatDate( model.MyDatetimeAttr )  </div>.
```

`FormatDate` would be my javascript function. The main question is how to call javaScript function between HTML tags?

Comment: Firstly `model.MyDatetimeAttr.toString("dd MMM yyy")` is not a heavy call. If that's taking too much time, you have some much bigger issues somewhere. Secondly, you don't put JS in HTML tags. You place it in `<script>` tags (or reference it externally in them) and run it when the DOM has loaded to then amend the Elements within the DOM

Comment: The alternative is to get the date in the format you want it initially - ie as a string, not as a date.  This is generally bad practice, but if performance of your web server is the issue, perhaps your database server has better hardware.

Comment: Out of interest, how did you narrow this down as the cause of your performance issue? Does your page run fine if you remove the `ToString` call on your datetime?